Android Studio, how to print unicode output from kotlin scratch file
Need to test some operations on Greek text. Sure enough, the scratch file accepts something like
var testString = "θερμοσίφωνας"

However any println("θερμοσίφωνας") will give me ????????????
I have always been able to find a solution searching stack overflow. Not this time!
Settings > File Encodings > Global & Project both set to UTF-8
tried
var testString = "θερμοσίφωνας"
println(testString)

or
println("θερμοσίφωνας") 

Log.d from scratch file possible?

Anyone? Need more information or is this a sillly question?

I can't reproduce the issue, using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 on Ubuntu Linux. Perhaps this is something dependent on your environment. It could be something like the fonts used in the scratch output window don't support Greek characters.

@k314159 thanks for trying. As stated I use Kotlin scratch file. I cannot find a Setting that shows or may change the font used in the scratch output window.
